# How to get the DB2 version installed in the machine whether it is 32bit or 64bit using batch file in windows

Tags: batch-file, db2, db2-luw

How to get the DB2 version installed in the machine whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit using batch file command in windows?

Answer (score 3):

Try this inside the bat file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%i in ('db2level ^| findstr "bits"') do echo %%i
```

Comment: Mark- It's not working only "Instance" is getting printed on the command line.

Comment: Wha't the exact output of the following command on your server? `db2level`

Comment: `db2level` command can't return just 'Instance' output. It's some very strange installation if so.

Comment: Thanks @Mark your code is working...only a thing we need to change is token from 2 to 5 as mentioned below------>       for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%i in ('db2level ^| findstr "bits"') do echo %%i.................acknowledge this as you see my comments

Answer (score 2):

On the server you run `db2level`; when connecting remotely using `db2 connect to yourdb` the server version and bitness will be printed on the console like so:

```
   Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2/LINUXX8664 11.1.9.0
SQL authorization ID   = YOURID
Local database alias   = YOURDB
```

Comment: You didn't got me.... i want the result on windows batch file...and db2 software is installed on my machine... need batch file command for that

Comment: My question is- How to get the DB2 version installed in the machine whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit using batch file command in windows?

Comment: Got my answer here is the code............ for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%i in ('db2level ^| findstr "bits"') do echo %%i